# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri

Tags: java, android, permissions, uri

[image]

**The Situation:**

I decremented a Uri

- **First**, I converted the Uri into a string and in turn into an int

  **Afterwhich**, I did a -1, and then I got the string that looks exactly like a decremented string

  **However**, when I parse the uri and try to setImageURI() on it,

  it is showing *"File error accessing recents directory (directory

  doesn't exist?)*."

Here is the code that I have used:

```
            Uri ImageUri = data.getData();
            String uri1 = ImageUri.toString();

            //region uri2
            String substr1 = uri1.substring(uri1.length()-3);
            int substr1int = parseInt(substr1)-1;
            String decrementedstr1 = new Integer(substr1int).toString();
            int numberofchars1 = uri1.length()-3;
            String firstcomponent1 = uri1.substring(0, numberofchars1);
            String uri2 = firstcomponent1 + decrementedstr1;


            //endregion
            Uri test = Uri.parse(uri2);
            animateobject.setImageURI(test);
```

Got this Error:

> File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).

After I used 'Debug App', it showed the error in more details:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
> com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri
> content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1000002538
> from pid=1309, uid=10925 requires that you obtain access using
> ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

**Note:** This is in java and I'm using Android Studio to code.

Comment: No. Where did you get that string from? It's an impossible content scheme to begin with.

Comment: What class is Uri from?

Comment: @blackapps it is an example.. the real uri that I got is.. content://com.android.providers.media...../document/image%3A1000002538 . I'm required to increment the numbers by 1 and thus I have to convert it into a string and parse it back to uri. The problem is that the %3A is causing my string to be converted into a wrong directory for the uri.

Comment: @JohnWilliams MainActivity class

Comment: Do this:   System.out.println(java.net.URLDecoder.decode("content://image%3A1000002539", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
. Note that the %3A becomes a : - not sure that fixes the problem

Comment: `I'm required to increment the numbers by 1 and thus I have to convert it into a string and parse it back to uri.` That content scheme is already a string so i wonder what you have to convert. And what is simpler then to substring the number, convert it to integer, increment it, convert it back to string and concat it behind the %3A. Then you have your new content scheme which you can parse to an uri. Pretty unclear about which directory you are talking. Come to the point.

Comment: Alright. Basically, I decremented a Uri (I converted the Uri into a string and in turn into an int, I did a -1, and then I got the string that looks exactly like a decremented string but when I parse the uri and try to setImageURI() on it, it is showing "File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).")

Comment: Hi to all those that replied. I'm thankful for looking into my situation. I have rephrased the question more clearly along with the code that led to the error.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find an answer to your question. Please don't edit answers into your question. Instead, use the answer field below and "Post Your Answer" you can even [accept your own answer](/help/self-answer) after 48 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first get something straight.  What is the meaning of that `%` character?

Well ... if you look at the URI Specification (RFC ....) the `%` is a [percent encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-12) marker.  The two characters after the `%` are hex digits, and the whole thing represents an ASCII character.  In fact, `%3A` represents the colon character (`:`).   So the unencoded "opaque" component of that URI is actually

```
//com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:1000002538
```

Thus, the image (document) number is *really* `1000002538` and decrementing it should give `1000002537` as the image number.

I'm not entirely sure why your "string bashing" approach is failing, but you are decrementing just the last 3 digits of the image numbers ... and your example has 4 significant digits on the right end.

So here's how you *should* code it:

```
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        String[] pathSegments = imageUri.getSchemeSpecificPart().split("/");
        String lastSegment = pathSegments[pathSegmentslength - 1);

        String[] parts = lastSegment.split(":");
        assert parts.length == 1 && "image".equals(parts[0]);
        long imageNo = Long.parseLong(parts[1]);
        imageNo--;
        lastSegment = "image:" + imageNo;

        pathSegments[pathSegments.length - 1] = lastSegment;
        String path = String.join("/", pathSegments);
        imageUri = Uri.Builder().scheme("content").opaquePart(path).build();
```

By calling `getSchemeSpecificPart()` we are getting the relevant part of the URI with the percent encoding decoded.  Likewise, the `Builder` is going to re-apply encoding as required.

CAVEATS

1. This code is not compiled or tested.  I don't have an Android dev platform.
2. For non-Android folks, this is using the Android `Uri` class not the Java SE `URI` class!

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work even for setText()..
The error showed:
 java.lang.AssertionError

Comment: Its a good answer. However, there seems to be an error at this line: assert parts.length == 1 && "image".equals(parts[0]);

Comment: So ... take a look at what is in the elements of `parts`.  Like I said, I can't debug the code.  (I assume that you understand the *purpose* of an `assert` statement ...)

Comment: Hint: add some traceprinting or logging before the `assert` to show you the information you need to look at.  Or use a debugger, single step it through the relevant parts of the code and examine the variables.  (This is a Q&A site for programmers.  It is assumed that you either know how to do these things already, or can self-educate on how to do them.)

Comment: Basically, I'm still not getting the result that I want. Oh well. I guess you need to have Android Studio in order to see what is the underlying problem. The solution that is being provided didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Well ... maybe you should tell us what your attempt at debugging / traceprinting has revealed.   Even for your original code. I doubt that anyone can help you without you telling us what the (incorrect) results of the rewrite actually are.  We know it is not what you want.  What >is< it?

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem has been fixed! Yes, I started using debug instead of relying on the logcat for the errors and it showed  Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1000002538 from pid=8290, uid=10925 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs   . Its a security issue. The solution is to use onActivityResult().

Comment: OK ... so that explains why I couldn't figure out why your original code was failing.  It wasn't!  However the thing I pointed out about your assumption about the number length IS true.  And that could translate into errors in ... one in one thousand cases.